# Is the ignored-setting in svn for files and folders only locally?

Tags: svn, version-control

If i add local files and/ or folders to be ignored by svn, is this setting valid only for my local checkout of the repository, or does it become a global setting for the whole repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't valid for just your local checkout.

The properties you set using `svn propset` will be set for the directory you specify. For example, to set the ignore property for a directory you've checked out:

```
    svn propset svn:ignore .project /path/to/directory/in/working/copy
```

`svn status` should show property changes with an '_'. `svn commit` to commit your property changes to the repository.

Comment: Subversion doesn't support inherited properties (yet). So the svn:ignore only applies to the directory itself.

Answer (score 1):

It becomes a setting for the directory you have set the ignore in, once you have checked in.

ie. If you ignore .settings in the docs folder, then .settings in the docs folder will not be committed on checkin.
If you ignore .s* in the docs folder then all .s* files will be ignored in the docs folder.

You need to commit for others to see the change to the ignore settings.